# Pyspark- How to remove extra quotes from a column names

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I have schema  with double quotes on column names in below data frame

```
DataFrame['"Name"':'string','"ID"':'double','"Designation"':'string']
```

i need to remove the extra quotes in the column names and data type
so it should look like

```
DataFrame["Name":string,"ID":double,"Designation":string]
```

i saw many example for removing quotes on column values but not on column names

so how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just a matter of [renaming the columns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed.html), and removing the quotes?. I.e.

```
df = (
        df
        .withColumnRenamed('"Name"', 'Name')
        .withColumnRenamed('"ID"', 'ID')
        .withColumnRenamed('"Designation"', 'Designation')
    )
```

Comment: Hi @Cleared, i need to remove single quotes ('') from the column name and data type

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the issue to be honest. Can you give a short example of how you create the DataFrame and the output from printSchema() as well as the expected output? Can you update the question with that information?